# Websites and web applications?

Tags: web, web-applications

(From the point of view of a user, not how it's built or which option is selected in Visual Studio)

...What is the difference between a "website" and a "web application"?

Is there a difference?

Are there characteristics that characterise the two?

Comment: If you're asking about the Website and Web Application project types in VS, you might want to clarify a ltitle or add the Visual Studio tag. Some folks seem to be confused.

Comment: Otherwise, you still might want to clarify, becuase that means I'm the one who's confused! :)

Comment: @Brian MacKay: As I read the question, IP wants to explicitly not ask about VS, but about the general definition of the terms.

Comment: To clarify - this was not a question about VS - it was a question about how a user perceives websites and web applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Software applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) are software tools designed to help the user perform specific tasks. Web applications simply provide a software application through a web interface. Think [Google Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_docs) as a typical example, but web applications can be much simpler.

On the other hand, a [website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website) can be regarded as just a collection of related digital assets (documents, images, videos, etc), relative to a common [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Comment: Voted up. We could complete the answer by saying that a website can be a part or an interface of a webapplication aimed to interact with human users.

Comment: -1: It seems like people aren't understanding that he's asking about Websites and Web Application Projects in Visual Studio, which are two specific solution types with different properties.

Comment: @Brian: It isn't immediately evident how the OP is referring to the solution types of Visual Studio. It looks like the emphasis is on "From the point of view of the user"... The question is not tagged "visual-studio".

Comment: I could be wrong then -- by user I assumed he actually meant to say developer. I asked him to clarify.

Comment: @Ian what are you talking about? The OP clarified that he does *not* mean this from a Visual Studio standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: I take the definition of a website from Wikipedia and deduce a definition of web applications from that (or, better, define differences between the two concepts). Everything in bold face is meant, put together, to build the definition of a web application.)*

Starting with the fundamentals: Is a web application a subset of a website? Following Wikipedia's definition of a website, that Daniel Vassallo has layed out in his answer, a website is a bunch of documents under a common URL. This also follows the [definition in the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/define.asp?key=89599).

A web application, on the other hand, is a bunch of web-based dynamic HTML and JS documents, together with images, CSS files and other documents, that is most probably, but not exclusively located under a single URL. The *purpose* of a web application comes below.

Hence we can state: If a web application is located on a single server only, without using client-side cross-domain techniques or extensive local storage (which I'd like to define here as everything beyond standard cookies and default caching), it is also a website.

Corollary: There can be web applications, that are not websites.

Hence we have to extend the definition of web application: **A web application, under certain circumstances being a website, is a set of interactive documents.** Interactive thereby means, that the user can do more than just follow hyperlinks to get from resource to resource. She can actively and in a well-defined manner change the state of resources. **The web application is, for this task, not confined to a single server, or to the server side at all.**

Now we yet have to define, where a web application ends and quite anything else starts. Therefore we state: **A web application has always an entry point, that is located at a website. If it has multiple entry points, they must all together be part of the same website.**

qed

*I am open for any suggestion on how this epic piece of wisdom could be refined to meet the requirements of reality. ;-)*

**Clarification:**
*This answer is in no way disrespectful to the question. However, I took a semi-serious approach, by which I mean, that the provided definition may or may not fit into one's personal idea of what a web application is compared to a website, but (and that is the serious part) is based on and deduced from a (possibly random) collection of facts.*

**Clarification 2:** *This answer has nothing to do with Visual Studio.*

Comment: @Ian no he is not. Read the question again.